# Split delimited strings in multiple columns and separate them into rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this dataframe `to_expand` with two columns:

`to_expand <- data.frame(first = c('a~b'), second = paste(list(c('1~2~3'), c('4~5~6')), collapse = '|'))`

```
  first       second
1   a~b 1~2~3|4~5~6
```

How can I turn it to:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  first second
  <chr> <chr> 
1 a     1~2~3  
2 b     4~5~6
```

I have tried using `sepratate_rows()` from `tidyr` but it gave all the possible combinations between the two columns.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

Edit: using `separate_rows(second, sep = '\\|')` gave me `a~b` on both rows.

```
> to_expand %>% separate_rows(second, sep = '\\|')
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  first second
  <chr> <chr> 
1 a~b   1~2~3 
2 a~b   4~5~6
```

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex. Try `tidyr::separate_rows(to_expand, second, sep = '\\|')`

Comment: hi @RonakShah, using `separate_rows(second, sep = '\\|')` gave me `a~b` on both rows. How can I keep `a` in the first row and `b` in the second row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do this in an easier way if we make the delimiter same

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
to_expand %>% 
    mutate(first = str_replace(first, "~", "|")) %>% 
    separate_rows(first, second, sep = "\\|")
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  first second
  <chr> <chr> 
1 a     1~2~3 
2 b     4~5~6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::separate_rows()` on multiple columns simultaneously if these columns are to be separated into the same number of rows.

```
to_expand %>%
   separate_rows(first, second, sep = "(?<=\\D)~|(?<=\\d)\\|")

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  first second
  <chr> <chr> 
1 a     1~2~3 
2 b     4~5~6
```

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps more transparent pattern is this:

```
to_expand %>%
  separate_rows(first, second, sep = "(?<=[a-z])~|\\|")
```

Herer we `separate_rows`**either** if there's

- a `~` *provided* there's a lower-case letter on the left **or** if there's
- a `|`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass different separator for different columns.

```
purrr::map2_df(to_expand, c('~', '|'), ~strsplit(.x, .y, fixed = TRUE)[[1]])

#  first second
#  <chr> <chr> 
#1 a     1~2~3 
#2 b     4~5~6
```